# Repeat list if index range is out of bounds

Tags: python

I have a Python list

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and I'd like to get a range of indices such that if I select the indices `0` through `N`, I'm getting (for `N=10`) the repeated

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

I could of course repeat the list via `(int(float(N) / len(a) - 0.5) + 1) * a` first and select the range `[0:10]` out of that, but that feels rather clumsy.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to use modulo with list comprehensions à la

```
a = [1, 2, 3 ,4]
[k % len(a) for k in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use the modulo operator when accessing the list, i.e.

```
a[i % len(a)]
```

This will give you the same result, but doesn't require to actually store the redundant elements.

Comment: But this will not work if you want to actually pass the list to an other function that isn't under your control (i.e. a built-in function)

Comment: @Bakuriu I know the question is missing context.  Depending on the use case, this might be a good solution though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

my_list = list(islice(cycle(my_list), 10))
```

Note that if you just want to iterate over this once, you should avoid calling `list` and just iterate over the iterable, since this avoids allocating repeated elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> (a*3)[:-2]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would offer a solution using the `*` operator for lists.

```
import math
def repeat_iterable(a, N):
    factor = N / len(a) + 1 
    repeated_list = a * factor
    return repeated_list[:N]
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> print repeat_iterable([1, 2, 3, 4], 10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
>>> print repeat_iterable([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print repeat_iterable([1, 2, 3, 4], 0)
[]
>>> print repeat_iterable([1, 2, 3, 4], 14)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about faking it? Python is good at faking.

```
class InfiniteList(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.data[i % len(self.data)]

x = InfiniteList([10, 20, 30])

x[0] # 10
x[34] # 20
```

Of course, you could add `__iter__`, support for slices etc. You could also add a limit (N), but this is the general idea.